# Handle Serialization and Deserialization with json schema using jsonschema2pojo

Tags: jackson, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

I have below json schema and generated java class using jsonschema2pojo library

**AddressSchema.json**

```
{
"$id": "https://example.com/address.schema.json",
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"description": "An address similar to http://microformats.org/wiki/h-card",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"address": {
  "type": "string"
 }
}
```

**AddressSchema.java**

```
public class AddressSchema {

 private String address;

 @JsonProperty("address")
 public String getAddress() {
    return address;
 }

 @JsonProperty("address")
 public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
 }
}
```

My requirement is to generate class with different values in @JsonProperty on setter and getter like below. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

```
public class AddressSchema {

 private String address;

 @JsonProperty("address")
 public String getAddress() {
    return address;
 }

 @JsonProperty("addr") //different value in the setter
 public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to use the same class to parse a certain json with different name `addr` and have it return with different name `address`. I don't see how it might be possible without using two classes and a mapper to map the values. As humans we'd think `address` and `addr` are pretty similar and there must be mechanisms to map them while `address` and `name` are totally different I wouldn't ask for them to be mapped. But for computers it would be a difficult feature to provide. Hope you get my point.

Comment: serialization and deserialization with different names from same model is possible using @JsonProperty with different values on getter and setter. My question was about to generate model class from the json schema!